# Proof of every measurable cardinal carries a normal measure

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I'm reading the proof of Theorem 10.20 in *Set Theory* by Jech and I don't understand the last argument.

The theorem says every measurable cardinal carries a normal measure. The proof goes: Let $U$ be a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. For $f$ and $g$ in $\kappa^\kappa$, define $f<g$ if and only if $\{\alpha<\kappa:f(\alpha)<g(\alpha)\}\in U$. Now let $f:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa$ be the least function with the property that for all $\gamma<\kappa$, $\{\alpha:f(\alpha)>\gamma\}\in U$. Let $D=\{X\subset\kappa: f^{-1}(X)\in U\}$.

Then we claim $D$ is a normal measure: Let $h$ be a regressiv efunction on a set $X\in D$. Let $g$ be the function defined by $g(\alpha)=h(f(\alpha))$. As $g(\alpha)<f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in f^{-1}(X)$, we have $g<f$. **Here is the part I don't understand: It follows by minimality of $f$ that $g$ is constant on some $Y\in U$. Hence $h$ is constant on $f(Y)$ and $f(Y)\in D$.**

Why does it follow from the minimality of $f$ that $g$ is constant on some $Y\in U$? And $h$ is constant on $f(Y)$ and $f(Y)\in D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By minimality of $f$, we have $$\{\alpha:g(\alpha)\le\gamma\}\in U $$ for some $\gamma,$ so by $\kappa$-completeness, there is a $\beta \le \gamma$ such that $\{\alpha:g(\alpha)=\beta\}\in U.$

(Your other questions can be answered by straightforward definition chasing. For instance that $h$ is constant on $f(Y)$ is a trivial consequence of $g$ being constant on $Y.$)

Comment: Use the equivalent definition of $\kappa$-completeness: $U$ is a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $S$ iff for every partition of $S=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}X_\alpha$ where $\gamma<\kappa$, there must be some $X_\alpha\in U$? And here the partition of $S$ is $\{\alpha:g(\alpha)> \gamma\}\cup \bigcup_{\delta\leq\gamma} \{\alpha:g(\alpha)=\delta\}$?

Comment: @user500144 Yes, that's right.

Comment: How about just using the original definition of $\kappa$-completeness? What collection of less than $\kappa$ sets can you intersect to get $\{\alpha:g(\alpha)=\beta\}\in U$ for some $\beta\leq\gamma$?

Comment: The way I would think about it is that $\kappa$-completeness means the union of less than $\kappa$ measure zero sets is measure zero. (So since the union $\bigcup_{\beta\le \gamma} \{\alpha:g(\alpha)=\beta\}$ is measure one, there must be a measure one set in there somewhere.) This is a complemented version of the original definition, that the intersection of less than $\kappa$ measure one sets is measure one.

Comment: @user500144 To use the intersection version of the definition of $\kappa$-completeness, proceed by contradiction. If none of the sets $\{\alpha:g(\alpha)=\beta\}$ for $\beta<\gamma$ were in $U$, then their complements would all be in $U$, and then the intersection of those (fewer than $\kappa$) complements would be in $U$. That intersection is $\{\alpha:g(\alpha)\geq\gamma\}$, which we already know is not in $U$.

Comment: It was shown  to be consistent that $|E|=1$ and consistent that $|E|=2^{2^{\kappa}}$ where $E$ is the set of all normal free $\kappa$-complete ultrafilters on $\kappa$, but it was an open Q whether $|E|$ could be anything else.... Is it still an open  Q?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet This is **way** above my pay grade, but no I don’t believe it is open any longer, or at least not as open as you describe it. See “the number of normal measures” by Friedman and Magidor, ca. 2008.